# ES6 Arrow Functions and Promise Chaining condensed syntax explanation

Tags: javascript, syntax, promise, arrow-functions, chaining

In the following code block, can someone please provide links or an explanation for the condensed alert statement syntax.

I understand the preceding expanded equivalent code that is commented out and contains the message parameter. However, I cannot find a reference to the syntax for omitting the message parameter:

```
      let timeoutPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('Success!');
        }, 2000);
      });

/*          timeoutPromise.then(message => {
                      alert(message);
                    }) 
*/        
       timeoutPromise.then(alert);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `.then()`, it expects you to pass it a function reference and when that function is called, it will be passed one argument that is the resolved value of the promise.

One way to do that is like this:

```
 somePromise.then(result => {
     console.log(result);
 });
```

Here the function you are passing to `.then()` is an inline, anonymous, arrow function.

But, you can also create a regular named function:

```
function showMyValue(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

And, then pass it:

```
somePromise.then(showMyValue);
```

That's the exact same signature.  You're passing a function reference and, when that function is called, that function expects one argument.

Well, `alert()` is also a function that, when called, expects one argument so you can also do:

```
somePromise.then(alert);
```

Comment: "when that function is called, it will be passed one argument that is the resolved value of the promise.", in fact. Any documentation for this? I have similar question when first see the just alert without explicitly pass the resolved parameter

Comment: @user1169587 - This is the [promise specification in ECMAScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-performpromisethen).  You pass a function reference to `.then(fn)` and it calls that function sometime later (if/when the promise resolves) with one argument which is the resolved value of the promise.

Answer (score 2):

What is `message => { alert(message); }`? It's a function that takes one argument and, when called, will pop up an alert dialog.

Now, what is `alert`? It's a function that takes one argument and, when called, will pop up an alert dialog.

A `foo => bar(foo)` wrapper is almost always superfluous and equivalent to just `bar`.